# Identify hematophagous insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

There's a small insect that seems to enjoy residing near trees and takes blood meals. The pain is sharp, comparable to being stung by a wasp.

I'm located in Serbia, Eastern Europe, bordering Hungary and Romania. It's currently August, warm and very moist from the grass being regularly sprinkled.

[image: Insect]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an "aphid lion", a larva of a lacewing (family Chrysopidae). They eat aphids and other small animals, not blood, but are capable of biting humans. [Here](http://citybugs.tamu.edu/2010/10/20/natures-freddy-krueger/) is a text about that (seems reasonable even with the silly title). It also says that "When a lacewing larva bites a human, it’s likely that any persistent itch or redness is due to the saliva injected at the site of the bite" so that would explain your pain.

Comment: Great! Apparently, they seem so beneficial you can't simply swat them off your person.

Comment: yes, just keep them off your skin!